# Ruby installation: BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20220324)

Tags: compiling, ruby

Can't install Ruby, I used the command lines below before:

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential tklib zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libreadline-dev

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
exec zsh
```

Thank tried to run: `rbenv install 3.0.3`

But keep getting this error:

```
Downloading ruby-3.0.3.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.0/ruby-3.0.3.tar.gz
error: failed to download ruby-3.0.3.tar.gz

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20220324)
```

Comment: Hello. What does this statement from your question mean? <Thank tried to run> The error is pretty clear in the path you have given there is no such app named that. Use a browser go to the directory and verify it is there and or what the name should be.

Answer (score 5):

> Apparently Ubuntu and its newer derivatives come with OpenSSL 3.0 and
> in this case Ruby versions earlier than 3.1 used OpenSSL 1.1
>
> In this case, the safest option is to follow the user manual and
> manually compile OpenSSL 1.1.
>
> It worked for me too with Pop!_OS and asdf
>
> PS: I put the export inside my .zshrc

**Install the dependencies:**

`sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall zlib1g-dev`

**Download OpenSSL 1.1.1:**

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1n.tar.gz
tar xf openssl-1.1.1n.tar.gz
```

**Compile it:**

```
cd ~/Downloads/openssl-1.1.1n
./config --prefix=/opt/openssl-1.1.1n --openssldir=/opt/openssl-1.1.1n shared zlib
make
make test
sudo make install
```

**Link the system's certs to OpenSSL 1.1.1 directory:**

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/openssl-1.1.1n/certs
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs /opt/openssl-1.1.1n
```

**Use RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl-1.1.1n before the command to install the ruby version:**

`RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl-1.1.1n rbenv install 2.7.6`

**If you want to make this permanent, add this line to you .bashrc or .zshrc file:**

`export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl-1.1.1n/"`

Then you don't need to use RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl-1.1.1n before the command anymore.

**Font:**
https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/1940#discussioncomment-2663209

Comment: I tried with openssl1.0.2u before but it didnt work. This one worked!

Comment: Wish I'd found this a few hours ago!  I saw the version change, but ignored it because I thought I was long past that as an issue today.  Not true!

Answer (score 1):

For ruby-build 20240119 you'll need to do this:

#For 'BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 on x86_64 using ruby-build 20240119)'

```
:~$ sudo apt install \
build-essential libxml2 libssl-dev libffi-dev \
libffi8 libyaml-dev libreadline-dev
```

Then:

```
asdf install ruby 3.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Ruby and Ruby environment newer than the Ubuntu `rbenv` package.

`sudo apt install rbenv`

`rbenv install -l | grep VERSION`

Check your preferable version is available or not.

---

If it's not, you can update latest list from git and remove `ruby` package of ubuntu beforehand (for making this simple).

`cd $HOME`

`git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv`

`git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build`

Check your version available.
Before install new environment, you must tell a new path to the shell

Add this code at the end of `.bash_profile`

```
# For rbenv
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" 
eval "$(~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init -)"
```

Restart your terminal or `source .bash_profile`
If the path of `rbenv` correctly set by `which rbenv`, it replies `/home/USER/.rbenv/bin/rbenv`

`rbenv install VERSION`
`rbenv rehash`
`rbenv global VERSION`

---

Confirmation

```
$ ruby -v

ruby 3.0.3p157 (2021-11-24 revision 3fb7d2cadc) [x86_64-linux]

$ which ruby

/home/USER/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```